# Can a server check whether a request is coming from an iframe (Node.js)?

Tags: node.js, iframe, server, cross-domain

1. I want my server to be able to check whether a request that came through came from within an **iframe**
2. If the request came from within an iframe, I want my server to be able to find the domain name of the **parent** of that iframe

Is any of the above possible and if yes how can I implement such a check in a `Node.js`/`Express.js` server?

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 1):

Just check the parent's url here:

```
request.headers.referer
```

If there is no iFrame, it will be undefined.

Comment: [Referer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) is the URL the user is navigating from. It can be the parent URL if the page is embedded in an iframe, but it can also just be the last page the user has visited. In addition [referrerpolicy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-referrerpolicy) can be used to block this from being sent to the server so the _absence_ of referer also does not necessarily mean the request is not coming from an iframe

Comment: Not reliable enough. You can have no referer but not be an iFrame.